# Functor to the empty (objectless) category?

Tags: category-theory, functors

My textbook says:

> Let $G$ and $H$ be monoids, regarded as one-object categories $A$ and $B$ respectively. A functor $F: A \mapsto B$ must send the unique object of $A$ to the unique object of $B$, so it is determined by its effect on maps.

The thing I can't understand is why $F$ **must** act in such a way? As far as I know, there exists the empty category with no objects at all, so one has freedom to define $F': A \mapsto C$ where $C$ is abovementioned objectless category.

Am I wrong?

P.S.
Seems like I try to interpret empty category $C$ as a fancy kind of monoid/one-object category, which has (logical surprise!) nothing inside and hence every statement about its internal structure is vacuously true. Not quite understand whether I am allowed to think in such a way or not.

Comment: The empty category is not a one-object category, because to be a one-object category it would have to have (surprise!) _one object_, which it doesn't because it has no objects. :)

Comment: Which textbook is this?

Comment: @DerekElkins, "Basic category theory" by Tom Leinster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is indeed a category $E$ with no objects (and therefore no morphisms). However, if a category $A$ has at least one object then there does not exist any functor $A\to E$.

Let's think about sets for a moment:

How many maps of sets are there from a non-empty set $A$ to the empty set $ \emptyset$? None! Because a map $A\to \emptyset$ needs to assign to every element $a\in A$ (of which there is at least one) an element in $\emptyset$; but there are no elements in $\emptyset$.

How many maps are there from a $1$-element set $\{a\}$ to another $1$-element set $\{b\}$? One! Namely the one given by $a\mapsto b$.

It is the same for functors:

A functor $A\to E$ from a non-empty category to the empty category needs to assign to every object $a$ in $A$ (of which there is at least one) an object in $E$; but there are no such objects!

Let $A$ and $B$ be two categories with exactly one object $a$ and $b$ respectively and let $F\colon A\to B$ be a functor. Then $F$ must send $a$ to an object $F(a)$ in $B$. But there is only one object in $B$, namely $b$, hence $F(a)=b$.

Comment: Do you need to have objects in order to define arrows in the category? Can we have a category with no object and only arrows? Is there any relation between objects and arrows? (In concrete categories, it makes sense but what about non-concrete category.)

Comment: Every arrow needs to have a source and a target, which are objects.

Comment: This is true for concrete categories but is it true in general? Are you viewing every objects as functions?